# I'm getting a repeated Server Error and not sure why

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating some programs that create a setup for a varying amount of players to interact in a simulation. Part of this is creating an individual player sheet for each player. I'm currently trying to copy over the round robin schedule to each individual player, and am continuing to get an error that says "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I've tried several times throughout the day and had others try, and it's still not working. I've included the code where it is stopping. This code is meant to open the individual spreadsheet, paste some values in and then do the same for the second player in the match.

```
      var player1SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(player1Id);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(player1SS)
      var player1Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      player1Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+1]+'3').activate();
      player1Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Round ' +i);
      player1Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+1]+'4').activate();
      player1Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(player1);
      player1Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+2]+'4').activate();
      player1Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(player2);


      var player2SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(player2Id);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(player2SS)
      var player2Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      player2Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+1]+'3').activate();
      player2Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Round ' +i);
      player2Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+1]+'4').activate();
      player2Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(player2);
      player2Sheet.getRange(alphabet[(i*2)+2]+'4').activate();
      player2Sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(player1);
```

As requested, here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aGqr_zrbtBhbMCA-zDqqD1w1fV40obIf-bBINv_tubg/edit?usp=sharing 
To successfully operate it, first you have to click generate tabs, then you have to put information into the player info sheet, then create individual sheets, then generate schedule, then fill individual sheets.

Comment: One person I had try had it work, but it only pasted in one value in a single individual sheet before getting the server error.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet, so that this behaviour can be reproduced? (removing all sensitive information).

Comment: I added it, just make sure to follow the order or you'll gut unrelated errors.